# Is using an assignment as an expression good practise?

Tags: c#

Would this be considered bad practice in C#.Net?

```
public T CurrentValue {
        get {
            return current;
        }
        protected set {
            AnimationUpdated(new AnimationChangedEventArgs(current = value));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What part of it? What do you mean by "this?"

Comment: current = value. assigning inside a parameter

Comment: It did and it works too.

Comment: That's the purpose of having a "set" in your property. To assign.

Comment: ok, I think I see what you're asking now - I misread the question. Yes, that's technically valid since "simple" assignments are expressions. No, it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that T is valid in this scope and current is declared as type T, this would work, but I would move the assignment to its own line.

It is a small thing, but I feel that it makes it more readable.  I keep variable assignments out of method calls.  IT also shows the intent to do two things.

Where I work, it would be considered bad practice.

```
public T CurrentValue {
    get {
        return current;
    }
    protected set {
        current = value;
        AnimationUpdated(new AnimationChangedEventArgs(current));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically that's syntactically valid (C# follows C in that regard - a "simple" assignment is also an expression) but it's confusing. It looks too much like "==" for one thing (in fact, people might initially think reading it that that's what you meant to do in the first place); it's also really easy to miss the fact that an assignment is happening because you don't ordinarily expect it to be happening there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with TychonOmega, however, I see that you are trying to raise an event when the value is changing.
Perhaps you should consider using an Observable type instead of doing this.
Take a look at these articles:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable(v=vs.103).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx